CSS: How to toggle the borders of a specific table column without twitching


function toggleBorders() {
  table.tHead.firstElementChild.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border');
  Array.from(table.tBodies[0].children).forEach(row => row.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border'));
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th.thick-border,
td.thick-border {
  border: 3px solid coral;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th> <th>h2</th> <th>h3</th> <th>h4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td> <td>12</td> <td>13</td> <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td> <td>22</td> <td>23</td> <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleBorders()">Click Me!</button>



Is there any way to toggle the column's borders without twitching?
And without thickening initial border width of other columns?
Maybe with shadows or gradients or somehow else

You could add transparent borders to begin with, and then only change the border-color.

Nicotine sure of your exact requirement, but make them thick from the start with transparent color will mean they won’t move.

@C3roe I updated the question, the idea is to thicken borders of a specific column

If you want the border to change width, how are you picturing the contents remaining in the same place? Are you expecting the other columns to shrink around it? Or some other effect?

@DBS I hope there is a way to do this using shadows gradients or smth without changing real border widths

You can use a box-shadow on either side instead.
 box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px coral, -2px 0px 0px coral;

2px / -2px extends it to the right / left, 0px offset on the y-axis, and 0px blur radius.


function toggleBorders() {
  table.tHead.firstElementChild.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border');
  Array.from(table.tBodies[0].children).forEach(row => row.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border'));
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th.thick-border,
td.thick-border {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px coral, -2px 0px 0px coral;
}
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th> <th>h2</th> <th>h3</th> <th>h4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td> <td>12</td> <td>13</td> <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td> <td>22</td> <td>23</td> <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleBorders()">Click Me!</button>




Since you were looking to style exactly the second column of the given table, I think it would be more readable if you defined such feature in stylings instead of using the convoluted javascript code you engaged in your own demo.
Here I just switched to border-collapse: separate to keep showing the cells right and left borders as styled and used an explicit css rule so that the whole table when having the class thick-border will be styled as that.
That way you just need to toggle the class on the table alone instead of each single cell of the target column.


function toggleBorders() {  
  document.getElementById('table').classList.toggle('thick-border');    
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {  
  border-width: 0 3px;  
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
}

table.thick-border tbody tr td:nth-child(2){
  border-color: coral;
}
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h3</th>
      <th>h4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleBorders()">Click Me!</button>




You may want to use a transparent border to begin with:


function toggleBorders() {
  table.tHead.firstElementChild.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border');
  Array.from(table.tBodies[0].children).forEach(row => row.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border'));
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

th.thick-border,
td.thick-border {
  border: 3px solid coral;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th> <th>h2</th> <th>h3</th> <th>h4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td> <td>12</td> <td>13</td> <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td> <td>22</td> <td>23</td> <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleBorders()">Click Me!</button>




Well and one more solution with pseudo-elements ::before and ::after


function toggleBorders() {
  table.tHead.firstElementChild.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border');
  Array.from(table.tBodies[0].children).forEach(row => row.children[1].classList.toggle('thick-border'));
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th.thick-border,
td.thick-border {
    position: relative;
    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        left: -1px;
        width: 3px;
        height: calc(100% + 2px);
        background: red;
    }
    &::after {
        left: unset;
        right: -1px;
    }
}
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th> <th>h2</th> <th>h3</th> <th>h4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td> <td>12</td> <td>13</td> <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td> <td>22</td> <td>23</td> <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleBorders()">Click Me!</button>



